# Dynamically creating an identical and independent copy of a neural network. JAVA

Tags: java, serialization, copy, neural-network, clone

**Context**
I am making a simulation of behavioral evolution. For this I am using neural networks to simulate behavior. There are literally thousands of these neural networks interacting with each other. At the end of any given generation the strongest behavior is copied onto its neighbors. When this happens I need to create an identical yet independent version of the stronger neural network onto the new one; thus replacing it.

**The Problem**
I have looked into deep cloning, it works but it is copying node references, not creating a new identical instance. The difficulty comes from the system structure. I can't see how to ameliorate it though.
Speed is a factor here as well. I need this to run millions of iterations a week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

System structure

The cell

```
public class Cell_NN Extends Cell
{
    private Network network;

    //Methods
}
```

The network

```
public class Network implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> net;
    private ArrayList<Node> layer;

    //Methods
}
```

The nodes

```
public class Node implements Cloneable, Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<Node> nextNodes;
    private ArrayList<Float> weights;

    //Methods
}
```

The deep clone (which I ripped off someone from stackOverflow)

```
public Network deepClone()
{
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(this);

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        Network network = (Network) ois.readObject();
        return (Network) ois.readObject();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am unsure whether this is allowed but here is my github in case you would like more information: Napier40124399. Project is called HonorsMain_v2 and is public.

Comment: Looks more suitable on CodeReview.SE. Did you really got problem with your code, like a StackOverflowError?

Comment: No errors, everything runs smoothly. It simply doesn't behave as desired.

Comment: Sorry to be hasty, because that piece of deep copy code just look fine and it is also the technique used by apache commons-lang's [generic cloning utility](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.java#L77). I think there isn't anything wrong within posted code. Maybe you should check other part of your software.

Comment: Ok, I will check other sections again. Thank you for responses. I'll leave the post up for a while just in case.

Comment: Read the anwsers below. I made a serious mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code contains just a small bug:

```
    Network network = (Network) ois.readObject();
    return (Network) ois.readObject();
```

Here you read the network twice from the `ObjectInputStream`, and return the second instance (which should be null). If you remove the first line, it should work.

The object is deep-cloned, and all references in the new Network instance are correctly wired to each other, not the original objects.

**However,** performance-wise this serialization / deserialization is pretty expensive. I recommend finding a structure which is faster to process if performance is of the essence.

For instance, two flat arrays for each network, one with the weights (as primitive floats or even ints) and one with int indices to the next nodes would be at least an order of magnitude faster to copy, using `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: Feeling pretty silly right now. Thank you. I will try to implement your suggested speed boost!

Answer (score 0):

This part of the deep clone code looks odd to me:

```
    Network network = (Network) ois.readObject();
    return (Network) ois.readObject();
```

Reading the object twice, and only returning the 2nd one... I would expect an exception here.